# UdpClient Send Not Working when Data is too Large

Tags: c#, .net

I'm deserializing an object and sending it via a UdpClient.

If I send two bytes of data, the data is received fine, but if I send the deserialized object as bytes, nothing is sent.

```
u.Send(b, b.Count(), "x.x.x.x", 1452); //does not work (b.Count()=3744)
u.Send(new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 }, 2, "x.x.x.x", 1452); //works
```

I assume this is something to do with the size of the data.

I'm trying to avoid TcpClient because UDP is faster, but would this work in TCP since it's streamed?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `u.Send()` return?  UDP does not guarantee delivery by the way.

Comment: It is a fallacy that "UDP is faster". It has lower latency _in some scenarios_, but for high-bandwidth scenarios, TCP actually has better throughput. It's simpler to implement as well. In any case, there is a fair amount of information already available on the web concerning maximum datagram size for UDP, and the effects of larger datagrams on transmission of them.

Comment: I'm starting to think this may be an issue with the destination firewall. Checking into it now

Comment: u.Send() = 3744 btw Micky

Comment: _"firewall"_ - I would not think so when the smaller send works.  3744 seems to imply it was successfully sent.

Comment: Not sure exactly what was going on. Sending less data worked perfectly, so I just condensed it down. Strange problem